# Unexpected close parenthesis in ternary operator PHP

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have a ternary operator which will echo styles for an HTML tag. I have tried erasing or adding parentheses but there's still an error.

```
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $us = $row['username'];
    echo '<div id="msg_guest" style="'.($us != 'Admin' ? ($us != 'inTELLigence' ? 'float: right; background-color: #51b8c1':'float: left;')).'"><div id="usr" style="'.($us != 'Admin' ? ($us != 'inTELLigence'? 'background-color: #67d5de':'background-color: #e6898a')).'"><div id="user">'.$row['username']. '</div><div id="time">'.$row['time_now'].'</div></div><p id="msg"> '.$row['message'].'</p></div><br />';
}
```

Comment: This is an example of how breaking the logic up into separate lines and sections would help you see the problem. Having one enormous line of code with ternaries is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not close condition completely for your first statement near `left;'))` you actually need `left;') : '')`

Replace

```
echo '<div id="msg_guest" style="'.($us != 'Admin' ? ($us != 'inTELLigence' ? 'float: right; background-color: #51b8c1':'float: left;')).'"><div id="usr" style="'.($us != 'Admin' ? ($us != 'inTELLigence'? 'background-color: #67d5de':'background-color: #e6898a')).'"><div id="user">'.$row['username']. '</div><div id="time">'.$row['time_now'].'</div></div><p id="msg"> '.$row['message'].'</p></div><br />';
```

with

```
echo '<div id="msg_guest" style="'.( $us != "Admin" ? ($us != "inTELLigence" ? "float: right; background-color: #51b8c1":"float: left;") : '' ).'"><div id="usr" style="'.( $us != "Admin" ? ($us != "inTELLigence" ? "background-color: #67d5de":"background-color: #e6898a") : '').'"><div id="user">'.$row['username']. '</div><div id="time">'.$row['time_now'].'</div></div><p id="msg"> '.$row['message'].'</p></div><br />';
```

Comment: oh i see. i have no else/false statement for the parent statement. Thanks!

Comment: @user5567987 yes. Please mark tick on my answer if you found my answer helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid nesting ternary operators as it can get quite messy quickly.

Your problem in this instance however is because you have a syntax error with the parent ternary statements. They do not have the else defined.

e.g. you need to end it with :

```
$trueBoolean ? 'true condition' : 'false condition';
```

Try something like this.

```
foreach( $result as $row ) {
    $us = $row['username'];

    $html = '';
    if ($us != 'Admin') {
        $html = $us != 'inTELLigence' ? 'float: right; background-color: #51b8c1' : 'float: left;';
    }

    $html2 = '';
    if ($us != 'Admin') {
        $html2 = $us != 'inTELLigence' ? 'background-color: #67d5de' : 'background-color: #e6898a';
    }

    echo '<div id="msg_guest" style="'. $html .'"><div id="usr" style="'. $html2 .'"><div id="user">'.$row['username']. '</div><div id="time">'.$row['time_now'].'</div></div><p id="msg"> '.$row['message'].'</p></div><br />';
}
```